# when using mongoose.model() getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

Here is my schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var test = new Schema({
    name : {
       type : String,
       require : true,
       sparse : true
    },
    description : {
       type : String
    },
    questions : {
       type : [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
       sparse : true
    }  }); 
    module.exports = new mongoose.model('test', test);
```

When I try to execute, it give me error as follows :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
at new Mongoose.model (/home/utkarsh/Desktop/MEAN_REST_user_management/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:329:25)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/utkarsh/Desktop/MEAN_REST_user_management/app/models/test.js:19:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/utkarsh/Desktop/MEAN_REST_user_management/app/routes/test.js:6:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
```

I have used the same format earlier, it worked fine. Dont know why its not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Remove the `new` in front of `mongoose.model()`

Comment: Thanks, Saved me lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
module.exports = new mongoose.model('test', test);
```

To this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('test', test);
```

[`mongoose.model()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model) isn't a class, so you shouldn't instantiate it (using `new`).